# WPF TextBlock: boxselection and multi-line editing

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

This is my first challenge with WPF.

I'm looking into the possibility of having [`Box Selection`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/26/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing-with-vs-2010.aspx) and [`Multi-line editing`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/26/box-selection-and-multi-line-editing-with-vs-2010.aspx) on a WPF TextBox.

Do you know if it is possible and if someone has already build this? Any pointers into the right direction are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to AvalonEdit: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx it is OS and very simple to interoperate.

Comment: It is a nice indication of what is possible. It doesn't have boxselection or mult-line editing however.

Comment: I ended up modifying AvalonEdit so it does support BoxSelection and MultiLine editing. Turns out RectangleSelection was in there already, it just wasn't hooked up properly.